# Fast algorithm for computing forces between $n$ point in the plane

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have a set of distinct particles $\{z_k\}_{k=1}^n\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ with dynamics

$$\dot{z_k} = \sum_{k'\not= k}V(z_k-z_{k'}),$$

where $V$ is a repelling Yukawa potential:

$$V(z) = \frac{\alpha}{|z|}e^{-\beta |z|}.$$

I want to numerically solve the equations. A naïve approach has complexity $O(n^2)$, but since the potential decays very rapidly I think there might exists a trick that gives us a faster approximate solution. Also I guess this problem has a more abstract formulation, like a graph theory formulation, so that we can reduce it to more known problems

Comment: This sounds like a problem from the wide field of [molecular dynamic simulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_dynamics). Some simple ideas: cutoff-radius and space partitioning (e.g. octree). Maybe also only update the force on a particle every $n$-th step or if it is moving fast.

Comment: A naive approach should have complexity $O(n^2)$, since one need only loop over all $n \times n$ pairs of particles, $(z_i,z_j)$, computing the force applied to $z_j$ by $z_i$ and accumulating that into $z_j$'s "currently applied force vector".  I don't see how this is $O(n^3)$.

Comment: @EricTowers you are right

Comment: @M.Winter that is precisely what I am doing now. Although the time decreased, I want to do it more efficiently.
Anyway, I am going to look for molecular simulations algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This paper seems quite relevant:

> [A Fast Adaptive Multipole Algorithm for Calculating Screened Coulomb (Yukawa) Interactions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999198961769?via%3Dihub), *Journal of Computational Physics*
>   Volume 151, Issue 1, 1 May 1999, Pages 212-241